# How to encode optional fields in spark dataset with java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, option-type, encoder

I would like to not use null value for field of a class used in dataset. I try to use scala `Option` and java `Optional` but it failed:

```
    @AllArgsConstructor // lombok
    @NoArgsConstructor  // mutable type is required in java :(
    @Data               // see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59609933/1206998
    public static class TestClass {
        String id;
        Option<Integer> optionalInt;
    }

    @Test
    public void testDatasetWithOptionField(){
        Dataset<TestClass> ds = spark.createDataset(Arrays.asList(
                new TestClass("item 1", Option.apply(1)),
                new TestClass("item .", Option.empty())
        ), Encoders.bean(TestClass.class));

        ds.collectAsList().forEach(x -> System.out.println("Found " + x));
    }
```

Fails, at runtime, with message `File 'generated.java', Line 77, Column 47: Cannot instantiate abstract "scala.Option"`

---

Question: Is there a way to encode optional fields without null in a dataset, using java?

Subsidiary question: btw, I didn't use much dataset in scala either, can you validate that it is actually possible in scala to encode a case class containing Option fields?

---

Note: This is used in an intermediate dataset, i.e something that isn't read nor write (but for spark internal serialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use normal Java Optionals in the data class and then use  [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) as serializer.

```
Encoder en = Encoders.kryo(TestClass.class);

Dataset<TestClass> ds = spark.createDataset(Arrays.asList(
        new TestClass("item 1", Optional.of(1)),
        new TestClass("item .", Optional.empty())
), en);

ds.collectAsList().forEach(x -> System.out.println("Found " + x));
```

Output:

```
Found TestClass(id=item 1, optionalInt=Optional[1])
Found TestClass(id=item ., optionalInt=Optional.empty)
```

There is a downside when using Kryo: this encoder encodes in a binary format:

```scala
ds.printSchema();
ds.show(false);
```

prints

```
root
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[01 00 4A 61 76 61 53 74 61 72 74 65 72 24 54 65 73 74 43 6C 61 73 F3 01 01 69 74 65 6D 20 B1 01 02 02]|
|[01 00 4A 61 76 61 53 74 61 72 74 65 72 24 54 65 73 74 43 6C 61 73 F3 01 01 69 74 65 6D 20 AE 01 00]   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

An udf-based solution to get the normal output columns  of a dataset encoded with Kryo describes [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188142/2129801).

---

Maybe a bit off-topic but probably a start to find a long-term solution is to look at the code of [JavaTypeInference](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/JavaTypeInference.scala). The methods [serializerFor](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75003fc99fa2f66622c2accca5e48842acc4c90c/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/JavaTypeInference.scala#L367) and [deserializerFor](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75003fc99fa2f66622c2accca5e48842acc4c90c/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/JavaTypeInference.scala#L209) are used by [ExpressionEncoder.javaBean](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75003fc99fa2f66622c2accca5e48842acc4c90c/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder.scala#L67) to create the serializer and deserializer part of the encoder for Java beans.

In this [pattern matching block](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75003fc99fa2f66622c2accca5e48842acc4c90c/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/JavaTypeInference.scala#L393)

```scala
typeToken.getRawType match {
   case c if c == classOf[String] => createSerializerForString(inputObject)
   case c if c == classOf[java.time.Instant] => createSerializerForJavaInstant(inputObject)
   case c if c == classOf[java.sql.Timestamp] => createSerializerForSqlTimestamp(inputObject)
   case c if c == classOf[java.time.LocalDate] => createSerializerForJavaLocalDate(inputObject)
   case c if c == classOf[java.sql.Date] => createSerializerForSqlDate(inputObject)
   [...]
```

there is the handling for `java.util.Optional` missing. It could probably be added here as well as in the corresponding [deserialize method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75003fc99fa2f66622c2accca5e48842acc4c90c/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/JavaTypeInference.scala#L225). This would allow Java beans to have properties of type `Optional`.

Comment: As you mentioned, the problem with kryo is that I loose the column-encoding, which invalid the main usefulness of Dataset (it's better to directly use RDD then). So I won't be using that I think. Still it is the best answer so far

Comment: I like the opening on the spark code that would need to be patched. Someone want to make a PR (I don't think I'll find the time :) ?

Comment: I think the implementation of `java.util.Optional` is missing because it's not serializable and Java developers decided not to pursue it since it would mean more maintenance. And for this very specific reason, an additional implementation has been added by Spark as `org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional`

Comment: Well, it doesn't work either with `org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional`, as shown in your answer. Also, the goal here would be to replace serialized null value by `Optional.empty` and inversely, serialized Optional.empty by null or equivalent in stored files. Not store a serialization of Optional.

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly simple to do in Scala.

**Scala Implementation**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, SparkSession}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Stack-scala")
      .master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val ds = spark.createDataset(Seq(
      TestClass("Item 1", Some(1)),
      TestClass("Item 2", None)
    ))( Encoders.product[TestClass])

    ds.collectAsList().forEach(println)

    spark.stop()
  }

  case class TestClass(
    id: String,
    optionalInt: Option[Int] )
}
```

**Java**

There are various Option classes available in Java. However, none of them work out-of-the-box.

1. `java.util.Optional` : *Not serializable*
2. `scala.Option` -> *Serializable but abstract*, so when `CodeGenerator` generates the following code, it fails!

```java
/* 081 */         // initializejavabean(newInstance(class scala.Option))
/* 082 */         final scala.Option value_9 = false ?
/* 083 */         null : new scala.Option();  // ---> Such initialization is not possible for abstract classes
/* 084 */         scala.Option javaBean_1 = value_9;
```

3. `org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional` -> Spark's implementation of Optional which is serializable but has private constructors. So, it fails with error : *No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters*. Since this is a `final` class, it's not possible to extend this.

```java
/* 081 */         // initializejavabean(newInstance(class org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional))
/* 082 */         final org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional value_9 = false ?
/* 083 */         null : new org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional();
/* 084 */         org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional javaBean_1 = value_9;
/* 085 */         if (!false) {
```

Comment: Well, you described very well the problem but it doesn't provide a solution :\